# How to download data from a website introducing some parameters in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, web, download

I'm new in objective C and I'm having problems to find this.

My app is going to be: 1) user introduces a parameter, and 2) my app returns the data in a list.

I have to do this using a website, but i don't know how to know do the request, and then how to pick up and parse the info.

How can I start??

Comment: hi. check this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5)

Comment: You probably should be thinking about a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) interface with your server, possibly using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) technologies on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can handle the filter parameter in the server with a cgi or php, in the app, make the request and get the response.

```
1.- Get the parameter from the user like a NSString.
2.- Create a NSURL from the string (and the server adress string).
3.- The use the class method dataWithContentsOfURL from NSData to initialize a NSData object from the response url.
4.- NSData is really flexible, so you can do anything with it.
```

Note: dataWithContentsOfURL is synchronous, so if you want async, take a look at Grand Central Dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem clear to me what you are trying to do.
If you are trying to call a webservice with some parameters or just calling a website plus parameters in the end of it?

If webservice , just use the ASIHTTP Library located in here:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

If website, just append your parameter to the end of the string and call it.